# Small text-based RPG (v2)

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, random, role-playing-game

This is my first text-based game I made. It's very small because I just learned Python and wanted to start small, and then code bigger programs. I added some stuff since the last time. Please give your honest opinion.

[Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/100554/64958) is my original question about this game.

```
import random
import time
import sys

def fight_enemy_3(enemy_name, min_enemy_damage, max_enemy_damage, min_player_damage, max_player_damage):
    enemy_damage_dealt = random.randint(min_enemy_damage, max_enemy_damage)
    player_damage_dealt = random.randint(min_player_damage, max_player_damage)

    if enemy_damage_dealt > player_damage_dealt:
        print("Uh-oh! You died!")
        game_over()
    elif enemy_damage_dealt < player_damage_dealt:
        print("You killed the {enemy_name}".format(enemy_name=enemy_name))
        cold()
    else:
        print("You walk away unscathed, but the {enemy_name} still lives.".format(enemy_name=enemy_name))
        cold()


def fight_enemy(enemy_name, min_enemy_damage, max_enemy_damage, min_player_damage, max_player_damage):
    enemy_damage_dealt = random.randint(min_enemy_damage, max_enemy_damage)
    player_damage_dealt = random.randint(min_player_damage, max_player_damage)

    if enemy_damage_dealt > player_damage_dealt:
        print("Uh-oh! You died!")
        game_over()
    elif enemy_damage_dealt < player_damage_dealt:
        print("You killed the {enemy_name}".format(enemy_name=enemy_name))
        its_getting_late()
    else:
        print("You walk away unscathed, but the {enemy_name} still lives.".format(enemy_name=enemy_name))
        its_getting_late()

def fight_enemy_2(enemy_name, min_enemy_damage, max_enemy_damage, min_player_damage, max_player_damage):
    enemy_damage_dealt = random.randint(min_enemy_damage, max_enemy_damage)
    player_damage_dealt = random.randint(min_player_damage, max_player_damage)

    if enemy_damage_dealt > player_damage_dealt:
        print("Uh-oh! You died!")
        game_over()
    elif enemy_damage_dealt < player_damage_dealt:
        print("You killed the {enemy_name}".format(enemy_name=enemy_name))
        game_end()
    else:
        print("You walk away unscathed, but the {enemy_name} still lives.".format(enemy_name=enemy_name))
        game_end()


def intro():
    name = input("Enter you name: ")
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print("Welcome to the Wildlife %s" %(name))
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    time.sleep(1)
    desert()

def desert():
    print("You are in the middle of a Desert in Africa")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("All you see is Sand. EVERYWHERE!!!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You start walking")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You see a Snake")
    ch1 = str(input("Do you wanna attck the Snake? [y/n]: "))

    if ch1 in ['y', 'Y', 'YES', 'Yes', 'yes']:
        time.sleep(2)
        fight_enemy('Snake', 1, 7, 1, 7)
    elif ch1 in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'NO', 'no']:
        print("You slowly back away")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("You managed to get away from the Snake")
        mountain_2()

def game_end():
    print("Congratulations you finished lvl 1!!!")
    ch4 = str(input("Do you wanna play lvl 2? [y/n] "))

    if ch4 in ['y', 'Y', 'YES', 'Yes', 'yes']:
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        level_2_intro()
    elif ch4 in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'NO', 'no']:
        print("Thank you for playing")

def its_getting_late():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Its starting to get late")
    ch2 = str(input("Do you wanna go to sleep? [y/n]: "))

    if ch2 in ['y', 'Y', 'YES', 'Yes', 'yes']:
        print("You were stabbed dead last Night")
    elif ch2 in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'NO', 'no']:
        print("You stay up")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("You see a person")
        ch3 = str(input("Do you wanna attack the person? [y/n]: "))

        if ch3 in ['y', 'Y', 'YES', 'Yes', 'yes']:
            time.sleep(1)
            fight_enemy_2('Enemy', 4, 8, 1, 7)
        elif ch3 in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'NO', 'no']:
            print("You try to run away")
            print("But the Enemy is faster then you")
            fight_enemy_2('Enemy', 4, 8, 1, 6)

def game_over():
    print("You lost")
    ch5 = str(input("Do you wanna play again? [y/n] "))

    if ch5 in ['y', 'Y', 'YES', 'Yes', 'yes']:
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        intro()
    elif ch5 in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'NO', 'no']:
        print("Thank you for playing")

def level_2_intro():
    print("Welcome to level 2!!!")
    print("You got a spear!!!")
    mountain()

def mountain():
    print("You start walking up a mountain")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Oh no you see a a Tiger!!!")
    ch6 = str(input("Do you wanna attack the Tiger with you spear? [y/n]: "))

    if ch6 in ['y', 'Y', 'YES', 'Yes', 'yes']:
        time.sleep(1)
        fight_enemy_3('Tiger', 5, 10, 4, 8)
    elif ch6 in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'NO', 'no']:
        print("The Tiger killed you")
        game_over()

def mountain_2():
    print("And start walking up a mountain")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Oh no you see a Tiger!!!")
    ch6 = str(input("Do you wanna attack the Tiger? [y/n]: "))

    if ch6 in ['y', 'Y', 'YES', 'Yes', 'yes']:
        time.sleep(1)
        fight_enemy_3('Tiger', 5, 10, 1, 7)
    elif ch6 in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'NO', 'no']:
        print("The Tiger killed you")
        game_over()


def cold():
    print("You are getting cold")
    time.sleep(1)
    ch7 = str(input("Do you wanna make a fire? [y/n]: "))

    if ch7 in ['y', 'Y', 'YES', 'Yes', 'yes']:
        print("You made a fire")
        time.sleep(1)
        sleep()
    elif ch7 in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'NO', 'no']:
        print("You died")
        game_over()


def sleep():
    ch8 = str(input("Do you wanna go to sleep? [y/n]: "))

    if ch8 in ['y', 'Y', 'YES', 'Yes', 'yes']:
        print("You go to sleep")
        time.sleep(2)
        you_slept()
    elif ch8 in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'NO', 'no']:
        print("You stay up")

def you_slept():
    print("The next day you wake up")
    print("You keep on walking")
    print("You see a person")
    ch9 = str(input("Do you wanna attck the person? [y/n]: "))

    if ch9 in ['y', 'Y', 'YES', 'Yes', 'yes']:
        print("You attack the person")
        time.sleep(1)
        fight_enemy_4('Enemy', 1, 7, 1, 7)
    elif ch9 in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'NO', 'no']:
        print("It turns out the person is nice and want to be friends")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("You have a friend now")
        friends()


def fight_enemy_4(enemy_name, min_enemy_damage, max_enemy_damage, min_player_damage, max_player_damage):
    enemy_damage_dealt = random.randint(min_enemy_damage, max_enemy_damage)
    player_damage_dealt = random.randint(min_player_damage, max_player_damage)

    if enemy_damage_dealt > player_damage_dealt:
        print("Uh-oh! You died!")
        game_over()
    elif enemy_damage_dealt < player_damage_dealt:
        print("You killed the {enemy_name}".format(enemy_name=enemy_name))
        you_killed_him()
    else:
        print("You walk away unscathed, but the {enemy_name} still lives.".format(enemy_name=enemy_name))
        you_killed_him()


def you_killed_him():
    print("You keep walking")


def friends():
    print("You and your friend combined powers")




intro()
```

Answer (score 5):

## Design

As it stands, in order for you to create "stages" you create multiple functions, each containing many `if` statements, each determining which function or "stage" is going to be run next. This isn't a great way to do this, and it can make code very hard to read.

I've actually created a library, along with the help of a few other users, which makes creating adventure games like this *much* easier. It's called Cactus, and you can find the repository [here](https://github.com/ShearOfDoom/Cactus), along with the download links. You can also visit the [website](http://shearofdoom.github.io/Cactus/).

*From the official docs:*

> **Imports**
>
> It’s super easy to import Cactus into your project. Once you’ve added
>   `Cactus/cactus` to your `PYTHONPATH`, this is all you need to do:
>
> ```
> import cactus
> ```
>
> **Creating a cactus.Position instance**
>
> A `cactus.Position` instance stores relevant data about a position on
>   a `cactus.Flowchart`. For reference, here’s a list of the
>   `cactus.Position` attributes.
>
> - `"name"` - The position’s name.
> - `"desc_enter"` - The description to display when the player “enters” the position.
> - `"desc_exit"` - The description to display when the player “exits” the position.
> - `"choices"` - A dictionary of choices representing other positions on the flowchart. The key is what the user enters, and the value is
>     the reference key to the other position in the flowchart.
>
> Here’s how a simple `cactus.Position` instance is structured:
>
> ```
> cactus.Position({
>     "name":       "start",
>     "desc_enter": "Description on enter.",
>     "desc_exit":  "Description on exit.",
>     "choices": {
>         "choice1": "1",
>         "choice2": "2"
>     }
> })
> ```
>
> **Creating a `cactus.Flowchart` instance**
>
> Flowcharts are essential to Cactus. Flowcharts are how you stucture
>   the "map" that the player of your game will traverse. For reference,
>   here’s a list of the `cactus.Flowchart` attributes.
>
> - `"data"` - Stores the actual flowchart data as a dictionary.
>
> Here’s how a simple Flowchart instance is structured.
>
> ```
> FLOWCHART = cactus.Flowchart({
>     "data": {
>         "position_name": cactus.Position(
>             ...
>         )
>     }
> })
> ```
>
> **Creating a `cactus.Game` instance**
>
> The `cactus.Game` class stores general data about your game that isn’t
>   relevant to flowcharts or positions. The `cactus.Game` class is also
>   where event handlers and global commands are stored. For reference,
>   here’s a list of the `cactus.Game` attributes.
>
> - `"name"` - The game’s name.
> - `"desc"` - The game’s description.
> - `"prompt"` - The prompt to be used for entering commands.
> - `"invalid_input_msg"` - The message to be displayed when the user enters invalid input.
> - `"flowchart"` - The flowchart instance that has been created.
> - `"case_sensitive"` - If this is False, then all user input, and certain attribute values a converted to lowercase. If it’s True, then
>     none of that happens.
> - `"allow_help"` - If this is True, then the user can obtain help.
> - `"about_text"` - The game’s about text, including the reqiuired attribution text.
> - `"event_handlers"` - A dictionary of the event handlers and their corresponding functions.
> - `"global_commands"` - A dictionary of commands that can be executed anywhere, and their corresponding functions.
>
> Here’s how a simple `cactus.Game` instance is structured.
>
> ```
> GAME = cactus.Game({
>     "name":              "Game Name",
>     "desc":              "Game Description",
>     "prompt":            "> ",
>     "invalid_input_msg": "Invalid input",
>     "flowchart":         FLOWCHART,
>     "case_sensitive":    False,
>     "allow_help":        True,
>     "about_text":        "Write about your game here.",
>     "event_handlers": {
>         "position.Name Goes Here 1.enter.after": exit,
>         "position.Name Goes Here 2.enter.after": exit
>     },
>     "global_commands": {
>         "exit": exit
>     }
> })
> ```
>
> **Running your game**
>
> Once you’ve done all of the above, you’re ready to play your game.
>   Assuming you’ve created an instance of `cactus.Game`, named it `GAME`,
>   and everything checks out, all you need to do is the below:
>
> ```
> GAME.play_game()
> ```

---

## Removing duplication

Rather than (again) recreating the `fight_enemy` function to run a different function each time, you can add an additional argument to the end of the function signature, `function_to_run`. You `fight_enemy` function would then become this:

```
def fight_enemy(enemy_name, min_enemy_damage, max_enemy_damage, min_player_damage, max_player_damage, function_to_run):
    enemy_damage_dealt = random.randint(min_enemy_damage, max_enemy_damage)
    player_damage_dealt = random.randint(min_player_damage, max_player_damage)

    if enemy_damage_dealt > player_damage_dealt:
        print("Uh-oh! You died!")
        game_over()
    elif enemy_damage_dealt < player_damage_dealt:
        print("You killed the {enemy_name}".format(enemy_name=enemy_name))
        function_to_run()
    else:
        print("You walk away unscathed, but the {enemy_name} still lives.".format(enemy_name=enemy_name))
        function_to_run()
```

---

## Nitpicks

You're also converting the result of an `input` call using the `str` function in many places. This is not needed. You can just call `input` like this:

```
... = input( ... )
```

I'd also remove the various `time.sleep`s, it's a little annoying to have to wait when playing the game, especially when it's more than 1-2 seconds.